# Five-letter words are formed from the letters in PHYSICAL with no repetition. How many words contain the letter "$y$" in them?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I tried doing $1 \cdot  7 \cdot  6 \cdot  5 \cdot  4$ but that gives me a really small number, that I am sure is not right.

Comment: Maybe you'd find it easier to count the unrestricted choices and then subtract those that don't contain the $y$.

Comment: Or else choose $4$ from $7$ and multiply by $5!$

Comment: You should explain your reasoning rather than simply writing down a formula without an explanation.  If you try to explain your reasoning in words, you may see the step that you missed.

Answer (score 0):

To compute the number of 5-letter words from a set of 8 with Y in them is the same thing as computing the number of 4-letter combinations from a set of 7, then multiplying that by the number of ways of arranging 5 objects amongst themselves. This is because you are required to have Y, meaning you have 4 choices to actually make. Meanwhile, one of the 8 objects you get to choose from has been pre-chosen, so to speak, and because there's no replacement you don't get to choose it again, reducing your set to 7. The number of ways of arranging 5 distinct objects is of course $5!$. Given that $\binom{7}{4}=\frac{7!}{4!3!}$; $$5!\binom{7}{4}=5!\frac{7!}{4!3!}=5\frac{7!}{3!}=5\frac{5040}{6}=4200$$

And that is the answer, which by the way is exactly the same number of 5-letter words having P in them, or A, or any other letter. This argument is completely general.

Comment: The word PHYSICAL has eight letters.

Comment: Whoops! Rookie mistake! Thanks for letting me know, I'd better go fix it